# Django folder structure issues

Tags: python, django

Coming from an Apache / php world there is something i can't figure out searching for django Development best practices :

With symfony2 framework (or even java Play!) you always have a "public" folder and the webserver only serve files from this folder. Obvious Strategy for security reason it is also clear during dev process to put public files in this folder.

In django it is not clear at all : from my readings it appears as good practice to have a static folder at root level PLUS a Media folder for UGC files  and à template folder. No main "public" folder.

Can someone help me to clear my mind here ? Would't it be more secure to have one folder to contain all requests and protect the rest of the app ?

Tanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different types of 'static' files in django.

1. Bundled resources/assets with applications (css,javascript typically)
2. Any files uploaded by your users.

Since these are two different categories of static files, django offers two mechanisms to deal with them. As the first is more common than the second (you may not have an application that requires users to upload files), dealing with the first condition comes built in with django.

As per the standard layout, applications that require static files will include them in a directory called `static` within the application directory. Django will search for this directory inside any app that is in `INSTALLED_APPS` for static files. If you have files that are not tied to any app, you can put them in a separate directory. This directory should be added to `STATICFILES_DIRS` (a tuple) so django is aware of it.

Once you have done this, the `collectstatic` command will gather all the static files (from the `static` subdirectories in all applications in `INSTALLED_APPS` and any directory in `STATICFILES_DIRS`) and put them in a directory pointed to by `STATIC_ROOT`; this is so `{{ STATIC_URL }}` tags work correctly in templates.

Now, all you do is move/point/link the `STATIC_ROOT` directory so that its accesible from the web. Django expects that all files in `STATIC_ROOT` are accessible at the root URL that specified by `STATIC_URL`.

---

For user uploaded files, django is more hands off. All it really cares about is that you don't put your user uploaded files in the same place as the `collectstatic` command will be using to read its files - this means, that the `MEDIA_ROOT` cannot be a directory or subdirectory of `STATICFILE_DIRS` (if you have specified any directories here, typically this setting is undefined in vanilla django setups).

`MEDIA_ROOT` is a directory that django can manipulate by creating subdirectories under the root (see the [`FileField` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) for example).

`MEDIA_URL` is the URL prefix that points to the root for user-uploaded files. This is so that commands that generate automatic URLs for models work correctly.

---

As these are two different classes of static files, there are two different types of security and deployment requirements. For example, you might want to store user uploaded files in a S3 bucket but put your application's assets somewhere else.

This is why these two similar things are segregated in django.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all your static assets into a public/static folder with the command

```
> python manage.py collectstatic
```

provided you have set a static path in your manage.py

STATIC_ROOT = "~/mypath/public/static/"

Each app should have its own static assets.

Comment: Would you say the media folder should be in the public one as well and that I should contain all public files in one folder for security reasons ? Just as it is in Apache/php world ?